# Strange WinForms RichTextBox formatting effect

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to format a RichTextBox object with the following code:

```
public static void MessageString(RichTextBox textBox, MessageModel model)
{
    //textBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Consolas", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0);

    var message = new StringBuilder();

    // date
    message.Append(DateTimeString(model.RequestTime));
    message.Append(" - ");

    int start = textBox.Text.Length;
    int length = message.Length - 1;
    textBox.Text = string.Concat(textBox.Text, message.ToString());
    textBox.DeselectAll();
    textBox.Select(start, length);
    textBox.SelectionColor = Color.LightGray;
    textBox.PerformLayout();

    // reset
    message = new StringBuilder();

    // time and user
    message.Append(UserString(model.User));
    message.Append(" wrote:");
    message.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    start = textBox.Text.Length;
    length = message.Length - 1;
    textBox.Text = string.Concat(textBox.Text, message.ToString());
    textBox.DeselectAll();
    textBox.Select(start, length);
    textBox.SelectionColor = Color.Gray;

    // reset
    message = new StringBuilder();

    // body
    message.Append(model.Text);
    message.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    message.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    start = textBox.Text.Length;
    length = message.Length - 1;
    textBox.Text = string.Concat(textBox.Text, message.ToString());
    textBox.DeselectAll();
    textBox.Select(start, length);
    textBox.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue;
}
```

The problem is now, that the all text is formated with LightGray and only the body part os DarkBlue. The time and user part is also LightGray.
If i run this as part of a iteration list with more then one MessageModel, the whole textbox will be LightGray and only the last body part DarkBlue.

Actually i could not see the problem (forest, trees , u know). Each part should only select itself and formating it.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Every time you assign the RichTextBox.Text property you will lose any formatting of its content.  You can only preserve what is there by appending text with AppendText() or inserting/deleting text by assigning the SelectedText property.  Technically you can tinker with the Rtf property but that is very hard to get right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing these lines

```
textBox.Text = string.Concat(textBox.Text, message.ToString());
```

with

```
textBox.AppendText(message.ToString());
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)